# When trying to create a table in sqlight keep getting a exceptionKeep

Tags: java, sqlite

I'm trying to creat a table in sqlight. I use the following code
         // this will now through a exception becouse the table allready exist

```
  sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS exchangesd (\n"
                    + " id integer PRIMARY KEY,\n"
                    + " name text ,\n"
                    + " publickey ,\n"
                    + " privetkey L,\n"
                    + " phrase ,\n"
                    + ");";
         stmt.execute(sql);
```

The line stmt.execute(sql); generates a exception with the message

```
"org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near ")": syntax error)"
```

code:

```
void test()
 {

     ted++;
     try {

         Connection c = null;
         Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
         c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:ted.db");

         Statement stmt = null;

         stmt = c.createStatement();
         String sql;

         // this will now through a exception becouse the table allready exist
         sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS exchangesd (\n"
                    + " id integer PRIMARY KEY,\n"
                    + " name text ,\n"
                    + " publickey ,\n"
                    + " privetkey L,\n"
                    + " phrase ,\n"
                    + ");";
         stmt.execute(sql);  // EXCEPTION GOES OF HEAR

         sql = "INSERT INTO exchangesd (name, publickey, privetkey, phrase ) " +
                 "VALUES ('exchangea', publickkeya, 'privet keya', 'phasea' );"; 
         stmt.executeUpdate(sql);



     }catch(Exception e)
     {
         ted++;
     }
}
```

Comment: `publickkeya` ... is this a typo?  Why aren't you using prepared statements here?  Also, some of your table's fields appear to be missing types.  I see multiple problems with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extra `,` here:

```
+ " phrase ,\n"
+ ");";
```

and the SQL parser fails when seeing the following `)` when it is syntactically not possible.